# Configure tomcat for SSO using cas

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, cas

I am trying to create SSO login for two of my grails app. I managed both the app to redirect to CAS login page but the SSO is not working. I am prompted with the login page even if I have already logged in using the other app. I tried adding this to server.xml of tomcat

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
```

but still no effect !
I have to login via the CAS login page for both the apps. What am I missing. Please help.

Comment: Have you done all the steps at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Tomcat+Container+Authentication and added CAS to the Realm at the container level

Comment: I have not created the 'Realm', I am not sure what they are but apparently they should be configured so that both the app must use the same one. Can I get some help regarding this.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/realm.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to tak advantage of the gateway parameter in CAS, which is specified as part of the /login URI. Based on the CAS protocl, if this parameter is set, CAS will not ask the client for credentials. If the client has a pre-existing single sign-on session with CAS, or if a single sign-on session can be established through non-interactive means (i.e. trust authentication), CAS MAY redirect the client to the URL specified by the "service" parameter, appending a valid service ticket.

See here please for additional info:
http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol